# "Outline Highlight" effect on objects with geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I need to create "Outline highlight effect" on my objects

[image] [image]

controlled by geometry nodes. Something like in this topic:

[How to toggle/highlight interactable items?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35901/how-to-toggle-highlight-interactable-items)

but with the use of geometry nodes.

I've tried creating a material with inverted faces and "Backface culling", but this leads to 2 problems:

1. Lots of unnecessary "highlights".
2. Noticeably uneven color.

[image]

Please let me know if there is a way to fix these problems, or am I the wrong way and there is another, better way?

**UPD:
Another problem found:**

"Highligthing" disappears in some areas

[image]

Blend-file: [image] (Blender v 3.6.1)

Comment: I'm very sorry to say this, but *Geometry Nodes* are definitely not the right way to achieve something like this. I would rather look for a shader.

Comment: or maybe grease pencil? edge type: silhouette?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unity and other game engines this is implemented as a screen space effect. The geometry is dilated in screen space then a single color is applied to it, At the end the real geometry is drawn on top of it. So the effect you want to achieve would be done inside the compositor as a post-processing effect. The realtime compositor currently doesn't support cryptomatte though, but you could use other means to filter out objects.

[image]

Comment: There's also the lineart modifier as an alternative to geonodes.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady You are right, although you do have to use different view layers if you don't want the inside half of the stroke to be drawn in front of your object https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKFtP.png

Comment: @Gorgious
Hi! so I have a similar issue, I need to create an outline like OP but I need it to be a gradient mask going inwards, so I can essentially fray the edges of my objects silhouette in the shader editor. I have played around with your method, and blurring the outline it in compositing but I didn't manage to create what I need. I would GREATLY appreciate your help. Have created multiple posts and asked in blender discord but nothing yielded good results. Here is my discord if you would like to contact me there instead of here through the comments: lpoppi

Comment: Instead of distance mode in the dilate node you can use feather which will give you a gradient

Comment: @Poppi in case you didn't get the notification

Comment: Thank you.
Not the easiest way to achieve what I want but it works!